# Powershell event to trigger Azure data factory Pipeline based on creation of file on local drive

Tags: c#, powershell

As highlighted on my title, i need to create a powershell script event to trigger a Azure data factory pipeline.

I have found below script on [gallery.technet.microsoft.com][1] which monitors a folder for a file creation. what I wanted to do is, to trigger the Azure datafactory pipeline everytime the "SRmanifest.CSV" is created. 
Can someone help me with the next steps of the script to link up with ADF pipeline and this will help others who are in the same situation.

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
    $watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
    $watcher.Path = "c:\test"
    $watcher.Filter = "SRManisfest.*"
    $watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
    $watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
    $action = { 

##Install_Module AzureRM
##Connect-AzureRMAccount
##Import-Module AzureRM.profile
##Get-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser

##Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Undefined -Scope LocalMachine

##powershell Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
##get-azureRMstorageAccount |select StorageAccount

Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container "csv" -File "c:\test\SRManifest.csv" -Blob "amilablob"
$StorageAccount= Get-AzureRMStorageAccount | where {$_.StorageAccountName -eq 'amilablob'}
$StorageAccount= Get-AzureStorageContainer | Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name 'csv'
$Container = $StorageAccount |Get-AzureStorageContainer
$Container| set-AzurestorageblobContent -File 'C:\Test\SRManifest.csv' -blob 'SRManifest.csv'
             }
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
  while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried already / an attempt at solving the problem

Comment: I have changed the folder and customised for the filter. I dont know anything about powershell or C#

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 I have improved the script and latter part of the cript copies a file from local drive to azure blob (but wrong container) However, the full script doeant work. any help, please